# All my Nuget Packages have been uninstalled and wont redownload - very strange

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, maui

I am making a C# Maui app in Visual Studio.
The nugets have disappeared into thin air and wont redownload.
I dont think i did anything to effect the file. It must be something on my PC.

After ages of working Nugets packages. I suddenly have them with a red underline on my using statements.
i checked the package manager and all Nugets have been uninstalled.
I checked the `.csproj` folder and they are still mentioned in there as being installed.

```cs
using SkiaSharp; // not found
using SkiaSharp.Views.Maui; // not found
using SpaceInvaders.Levels;
using SpaceInvaders.ViewModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls; // not found
using Newtonsoft.Json; // not found
```

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="7.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
  <PackageReference Include="Plugin.Maui.Audio" Version="1.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp" Version="2.88.4-preview.84" />
  <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Controls" Version="2.88.4-preview.84" />
  <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Views.Maui.Core" Version="2.88.4-preview.84" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
</ItemGroup>
```

I have tried to reinstall and download the packages and dont get past the installer.
I have reinstalled VS on my machine
I have cleared my nuget cache.
I have googled the issue.
I have taken an older working version from Github and was met with the same error.
Has anyone seen or heard of such a thing.
All packages are gone. Im mainly using `Skia` but all the preinstalled packages are gone as well.

Comment: Are you on a corporate network? Is it possible the downloads are being blocked by your firewall?

Comment: "dont get past the installer." - what does this mean?  What specifically happens when you run the installer?  What does the nuget package manager log show?

Comment: Run dotnet restore in the root of your project and that will list the errors for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `dotnet nuget locals all --list` command? It should show you the Nuget package folder locations. Also please read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders), it describes the Nuget packages management in detail.